# Error: A non-null value must be returned since the return type 'Welcome' doesn't allow null

Tags: flutter

I am creating a simple app to post api.But it gives an error.The error is:

-**Error: A non-null value must be returned since the return type
'Welcome' doesn't allow null. lib/screen/my_homepage.dart:13**

- **'Welcome' is from 'package:post_data_to_api/screen/model/model.dart'**
- **Future  postData(String name,String job) async{**

How to fix the errors,please suggest any solution and thanks in advance.

The code is
model.dart

```
import 'dart:convert';

Welcome welcomeFromJson(String str) => Welcome.fromJson(json.decode(str));

String welcomeToJson(Welcome data) => json.encode(data.toJson());

class Welcome {
    Welcome({
        required this.name,
        required this.job,
        required this.id,
        required this.createdAt,
    });

    String name;
    String job;
    String id;
    DateTime createdAt;

    factory Welcome.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Welcome(
        name: json["name"],
        job: json["job"],
        id: json["id"],
        createdAt: DateTime.parse(json["createdAt"]),
    );
```

my_homepage.dart

```
import 'dart:math';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:post_data_to_api/model/model.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
class homePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const homePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<homePage> createState() => _homePageState();
}

   Future<Welcome> submitData(String name,String job) async{
  final response= await http.post(Uri.https('reqres.in', 'api/users'), body:{'name':name,'job':job });
  final data=response.body;
  print(data);
  if(response.statusCode==201){
        String responsetext=response.body;
  welcomeFromJson(responsetext);
  }
  else{
    welcomeFromJson({name:"nmaw","email":"email"});
  }
 } 
class _homePageState extends State<homePage> {
  TextEditingController nameController=TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController jobController=TextEditingController();


   // ignore: unused_field
   late Welcome _datamodel;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text("POST Data through API"),
          centerTitle: true,
      ),
      body:
      SingleChildScrollView(
        child:  Column(
        children: [
       const  SizedBox(height: 10,),
        
        TextField(
          decoration: InputDecoration(
          border:OutlineInputBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)),
          hintText: "Name",
        ),
        controller: nameController,
        ),
        const SizedBox(height: 10,),
         TextField(
          decoration: InputDecoration(
          border:OutlineInputBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)),
          hintText: "Job",
        ),
        controller: jobController,
        ),
        const SizedBox(height: 40,),
        TextButton(onPressed: ()async{
          String name=nameController.text;
          String email=jobController.text;
          Welcome data= await submitData(name, email);
          setState(() {
            _datamodel=data;
          });
        },
         child: const Text("Login",style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white,fontSize: 20),),
         style: ButtonStyle(
          backgroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.all(Colors.blue),
         ),
         )
        ],
        ),
        ),
    );
  }
}
```

main.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:post_data_to_api/screen/my_homepage.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title:"post api",
      home:homePage(),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This error you are getting because all variable in `Welcome` class are `required` and `NotNullable`.

When you are fetching data from `Apis` make sure all your `variables` should be `nullable` because you cannot control `Api` response.

Just replace this class with your's

```
 class Welcome {
    Welcome({
      this.name,
      this.job,
      this.id,
      this.createdAt,
  });

  String? name;
  String? job;
  String? id;
  DateTime? createdAt;

  factory Welcome.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) =>
  Welcome(
    name: json["name"],
    job: json["job"],
    id: json["id"],
    createdAt: json["createdAt"] == null ? null : DateTime.parse(json["createdAt"]),
  );
```

I hope this will Help.